# Show an Alert Dialog when a server socket accept a connection

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-dialog

I need to created a class that implements a server socket that wait a connection request from a client (in this case the web browser). After that I have accepted the connection, I want to show an alert dialog with two buttons to the user. So, at the moment, I have the class ready to use for the server socket, and a method that implement the Alert Dialog. How can i use the alert dialog method inside the server socket class for show the message with the two buttons? Here is the server class:

UPDATE: i have added the code for create an Alert Dialog after that the server has accepted the connection

```
public class ServerThread extends AndroidApp2 implements Runnable { 
    public void run() {
    try{
        if ( SERVERIP != null){ 
            handler.post(new Runnable(){ 
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    serverStatus.setText("Listening on IP: " + ip_address_conversion + ":" + SERVERPORT);                           
                }
            });
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
            while (true){
                Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                handler.post(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        serverStatus.setText("Connected"); 
                    }
                });
                try{                            
                    AlertDialog.Builder connection_alert3 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                            connection_alert3.setTitle("Connection Incoming");
                            connection_alert3.setMessage("bla bla boa");
                            connection_alert3.setCancelable(false);
                            connection_alert3.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                }
                            });
                            connection_alert3.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){

                                }
                            });
                            AlertDialog alert = connection_alert3.create();
                            alert.show(); 
                } catch (Exception e){
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            serverStatus.setText("Oops. Connection interrupted. Please reconnect your phones."); 
                        }
                    });
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }else{
            handler.post(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    serverStatus.setText("Couldn't detect internet connection.");   }
            });
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        handler.post(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                serverStatus.setText("Error");
            }
        });
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  } 
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // create the dialog here
            }
});
```

This will work, if the handler has been created on the ui thread, which I guess is the case, because your are using it for setting texts.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void showDialog(Activity activity, String title, CharSequence message)
{
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
 if (title != null)
 builder.setTitle(title);

 builder.setMessage(message);
 builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
 builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
 builder.show();
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added your method in my activity class and fixed the name of the parameters. So i have called this method inside the server socket class, but nothing happen... I'm missing something?

Comment: refer this :http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-show-alert-dialog-in-android/

Comment: Hi Android28! I saw your link but i already have implemented the Alert Dialog. My problem is that i'm not able to show it on the socket class. I follow the tutorial and @Pratik example but nothing. Have i to add the remaining code on my question?